# Log mining machine learning approach

Tags: machine-learning, data-mining

I am looking for guidance on a log mining problem I am encountering.

My dataset comprises of lines like this with low veracity:

I am trying to predict whether or not there is going to be a delay on future messages with looking at a window(?) of previous data. Assuming each of the requests messages gets a response and that the response time is the difference in timestamps.

> { (Time Stamp) (Type Of Msg) (Bytes Of Msg) (MTI Code) (Msg Unique ID) (Type2 of Msg) }

Type Of Msg takes  either (Request or Response).

The MTI Code is an ISO 8583 message type identifier. In essence, 0X00 messages are tied to requests while 0X10 messages are tied to responses with X being the deciding factor on what type of info this message conveys.

Msg Unique ID is a 16-byte cyclical ID (starts at 0001,ends at FFFF, then recycles)

Type2 of Msg takes two values, A and B.

What In your opinion would be a good start on this problem for a machine learning approach? I have read some papers on PCA but this seems simpler than what they were trying to achieve.

Thank you in advance for your time!